# Facing issue while converting Workflows to Flows in Salesforce

Tags: visual-workflow

Hi I am trying to convert Workflows to FLows. In the Case object workflow condition I have Owner:Queue.QueueName != 'XYZ' .. Now How to use/Convert  this in flow. When I am trying to search for Queue in Flow, it is not showing. Only Group and User is showing. Can anyone help on this
[image]

[image]

If I am trying to use Group I am getting below error
[image]

Comment: You need to use the [Get Records](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_data_get.htm&type=5) element to query the `Queue` object and find the queue with the name **'XYZ'**. Then, you need to use the [Decision](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_decision.htm&type=5) element to compare the `OwnerId` field of the case with the Id field of the queue. If they are not equal, you can proceed with the rest of your flow logic. If they are equal, you can either end the flow or branch to a different path.

Comment: Hi @TusharJadav, This is the Time-dependent Flow. SO I need to add this condition in Start only. Can you explain how we can proceed in this case.. Can we create a resource for this?

Answer (score 0):

A Queue is a Type of Group:

[image: Group Describe]

[image: Type Picklist Values with Queue expanded]

Using `Owner (Group)` will allow you to filter by a queue name.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply..I tried this ..But getting the error that I attached in main context